# Moving Horde, RoundCube and SquirrelMail address books

Tags: webmail

I have moved a domain of mine from one server to another. Both domains use Cpanel.

I have moved all mails that were stored on the old server to the new one and this is fine now. Many users use webmail server with one of 3 mail systems: Horde, RoundCube and SquirrelMail.

Even moving the /mail folder from one server to the other, all webmail systems have no contacts on their Address Books.

My hosting company suggested to go, mail account by mail account and export every address book importing them on the new system, but this method is insane because the domain has hundreds of accounts and I would have to login on every account.

Is there a method to move a directory from one server to another and get all moved at once? WHere Horde, SquirrelMail and RoundCube store their files for every account?